# Spring Security OAuth2 Authentication Server Behind Corporate Proxy

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, proxy, spring-security-oauth2

I currently have an authentication scenario where I have a client and a resource server on the same network, however, the Authentication Server is on a public cloud provider.  I am currently separated by a proxy that needs (url, port, username, and password).  I am not certain how to configure my Spring Security Resource Server to make calls to the Authentication server via a proxy, without setting a jvm level proxy that would force my client to need to go through the proxy.

Here is the simplest example I have:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@RestController
public class SocialApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
   
   @RequestMapping("/user")
   public Principal user(Principal principal) {
      return principal;
   }

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**").permitAll().anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(SocialApplication.class, args);
   }
```

config

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: myCoolClientId
      clientSecret: epicSecretKey
      accessTokenUri: https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://api.github.com/user

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
```

Comment: Did you ever got this working?

Comment: Unfortunately, I moved on before the problem was able to be resolved :(